# Corebluetooth write Hexadecimal Value for Characteristic

Tags: ios, hex, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to write Hexadecimal Value `NSString * const  SET_BUZZER_ON = @"0xef";` for a characteristic while the method `didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService` is called, I check if I am in the right characteristic then:

```
NSData* valData = [self dataFromHexString:SET_BUZZER_ON];
[aPeripheral writeValue:valData forCharacteristic:aChar type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

The code execute without issues, but when the method `didWriteValueForCharacteristic` is called, I got the Error:

```
Error writing characteristic value: The value's length is invalid.
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just figured it out, I had to init the `NSData` with `Bytes Array` instead of `NSString`:

```
const uint8_t bytes[] = {0xef};
NSData *valData = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeof(bytes)];
```